# C++/Qt defining/undefining QT_NO_SESSIONMANAGER macro

Tags: c++, qt, macros, c-preprocessor

I want to compile QGis which requires QApplication to have commitData() as well as saveState() member functions. Thought, they are put in a preprocessor if statement:

```
#ifndef QT_NO_SESSIONMANAGER
void commitDataRequest(QSessionManager &sessionManager);
void saveStateRequest(QSessionManager &sessionManager);
#endif
```

But `QT_NO_SESSIONMANAGER` is defined and these functions are not declared, nor defined. When I #undef the macro in the qapplication.h, I received undefined reference errors. So, it seems that I should resolve the problem in another way. 
I doubt if there have been a problem with Qt configuration I've used, because the session manager is defined in prebuilt Qt libraries, but it is not in the Qt I compiled Qt v4.8.2.2. It is also possible that I should send some arguments to qmake or gcc to define/undefine this macro. I searched a while for related material on the net & stackoverflow, but I found no answer.

Answer (score 2):

It is a problem with your Qt configuration. It seems your compiled Qt without Session management support (Support X Session Management, links in -lSM -lICE).

Probably, you do not have the sm-dev library installed on your system:

dpkg -l | grep libsm-dev

sudo apt-get install libsm-dev

Try again to compile your Qt's sources. Make sure Session management is enabled (yes) when you run qt's configure.